# marvel basic licence installation

Tags: api, elasticsearch, licensing, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-marvel

I am trying to install the free basic licence onto marvel for my elasticsearch cluster. I followed the instructions here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/license-management.html and ran the following command

```
> curl -XPUT 'http://es-master-01:9200/_license' -d @license.json
```

I didn't use the -u flag as I don't have shield. I got the following error

> {"acknowledged":false,"license_status":"valid","acknowledge":{"message":"This
>   license update requires acknowledgement. To acknowledge the license,
>   please read the following messages and update the license again, this
>   time with the \"acknowledge=true\" parameter:","marvel":["basic"]}}

I also tried

```
curl -XPUT 'http://host:port/_license&acknowledge=true' -d @mylicense.json
```

as I saw it suggested elsewhere but that didn't work for me either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's

```
curl -XPUT 'http://host:port/_license?acknowledge=true' -d @mylicense.json
```

with a `?`

not

```
curl -XPUT 'http://host:port/_license&acknowledge=true' -d @mylicense.json
```

with a `&`

Comment: Yep, that worked for me, thanks. Always something simple.